# Calling JavaScript variables in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know there are various threads on this topic. But I am wondering if my approach is entirely incorrect. I am trying to set the height of a wrapper depending on the browser size. So far I have this JavaScript function that returns the height and width of the screen.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var screenW = 640, screenH = 480;
if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion)>3) {
 screenW = screen.width;
 screenH = screen.height;
}
else if (navigator.appName == "Netscape" 
    && parseInt(navigator.appVersion)==3
    && navigator.javaEnabled()
   ) 
{
 var jToolkit = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
 var jScreenSize = jToolkit.getScreenSize();
 screenW = jScreenSize.width;
 screenH = jScreenSize.height;
}
</script>
```

I wish to call the values of these variables later in :
`<div id="wrapper" style = "height: valuepx; screenHwidth: screenWpx;>` in similar fashion to a PHP echo.

How should I be approaching calling the variable?

Comment: you are mixing PHP, Java, JavaScript and CSS. None of this will work.

Comment: have you considered using jQuery?

Comment: Isn't this is what CSS media-queries are for?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. No I have not considered it. I am new to JavaScript and CSS. What would be the best resource for me to read that should help me work this out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to assign the style from Javascript:

```
var wrapper=document.getElementById("wrapper");
wrapper.style.height = screenH;
wrapper.style.width = screenW;
```

or with jQuery:

```
$("#wrapper").css({
  width:screenW, 
  height:screenH
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Should inputting the first solution into my above function work if inserted correctly?